# Сообщения после удаление образа docker

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

После удаления старых образов docker командой

```
docker images --no-trunc --format "{{.ID}} {{.CreatedSince}}" | grep " months" | awk "{ print $1 }" | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rmi || true
```

в ответе, помимо удаленных образов выдается:

```
Error: No such image: 2
Error: No such image: months
Error: No such image: ago
Error: No such image: 2
Error: No such image: months
Error: No such image: ago
Error: No such image: 2
Error: No such image: months
Error: No such image: ago
Error: No such image: 2
Error: No such image: months
Error: No such image: ago
Error: No such image: 2
Error: No such image: months
Error: No such image: ago
Error: No such image: 2
Error: No such image: months
Error: No such image: ago
Error: No such image: 2
Error: No such image: months
Error: No such image: ago
Error: No such image: 2
Error: No such image: months
Error: No such image: ago
Error: No such image: 2
Error: No such image: months
Error: No such image: ago
Error: No such image: 2
Error: No such image: months
Error: No such image: ago
Error: No such image: 4
Error: No such image: months
Error: No such image: ago
Error: No such image: 4
Error: No such image: months
Error: No such image: ago
Error: No such image: 4
Error: No such image: months
Error: No such image: ago
Error: No such image: 4
Error: No such image: months
Error: No such image: ago
Error: No such image: 4
Error: No such image: months
Error: No such image: ago
```

И так далее по списку.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему он пытается найти образы с этими именами, и как я могу от этого избавится?

Comment: Видимо результат выполнения `docker images --no-trunc --format "{{.ID}} {{.CreatedSince}}" | grep " months" | awk "{ print $1 }"` не соответствует вашим ожиданиям. Практика показывает, что grep и awk в одной строчке - проблемы гарантированы. Может вместо таких read-only велосипедов вам `docker image prune` нужен?

Comment: К сожалению даже не догадываюсь, как при помощи docker iamge prune можно удалять образы, созданные более месяца назад. Не подскажете как это сделать?(кстати без awk вывод такой же)

Comment: docker image prune удаляет все неиспользуемые образы

Comment: Но мне не нужно удалять все неиспользуемые, в этом и проблема

Comment: *Useless use of grep*... А зачем это `|| true`?

Comment: Игнорировать ошибки, если не ошибаюсь. Они игнорироваться то игнорируются, но вывод в консоли всё равно появляется, но не могу понять почему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что конструкция с двойными ковычками в awk выдает вам полную строку

```
docker images --no-trunc --format "{{.ID}} {{.CreatedSince}}" | grep " months" | awk "{ print $1 }"
```

`sha256:77b81ca0096a195cb0bf682cb126551e2bc8e0866b503a79bf6caf9364242502 9 days ago`

Вот вы и получаете удаление образа плюс попытка удалить несуществующие образы :)

Собственно как вы догадались уже вот эта конструкция будет работать правильно

```
docker images --no-trunc --format "{{.ID}} {{.CreatedSince}}" | grep " months" | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Comment: Это две одинаковых строки, или я чего-то не заметил?

Comment: @АртёмТюрин все верно, две одинаковых строки, кроме двойных ковычек в случае с awk.